# ¿mostrar y ocultar columnas de access de una tabla?

Tags: .htaccess, access-control

tengo 7 columnas en mi tablas y pasa que deslice uno hasta que desapareció y no se como volver a mostrarlo.
**help me!!**

consulte foros de acces pero no me ayudaron

[Foro de access](https://support.office.com/es-es/article/Ocultar-o-mostrar-una-columna-quitar-o-agregar-una-columna-86e48dbb-b7bb-46bf-a0e1-456de1f99f7c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bien, lo que tienes que hacer es simple.

seleccionas tus columnas click derecho y Unhide(mi access es en ingles) Columns y seleccionas las columnas que  quieras que aparezcan

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]